# R programming - how to find frequencies for foor delivery data

Tags: r, frequency

New to R.

I need to find the some frequencies based on Vendor, day, location, order:

data:

```
Vendor            date         day    location       order                               qty.
Cassava           11/04/2020   Wed    Cupertino      老大哥 - 牛肉麵 Beef Noodle Soup      10
Cassava           11/04/2020   Wed    Cupertino      冷凍）老大哥 - LDG Frozen             5
Cassava           11/05/2020   Thu    Cupertino      冷凍）老大哥 - LDG Frozen             2
Joy  Restaurant   11/04/2020   Wed    SF              Beef Noodle                         10 
Joy  Restaurant   11/05/2020   Thu    SF              Beef Noodle                         20
Joy  Restaurant   11/04/2020   Wed    OAK             Beef Noodle                         30
```

want 1 (frequencies per vendor & order):

```
Vendor            order                             freq
Cassava           老大哥 - 牛肉麵 Beef Noodle Soup    10
Cassava           冷凍）老大哥 - LDG Frozen           7
Joy  Restaurant   Beef Noodle                        60
```

want 2 (frequencies per vendor, location, order):

```
Vendor            location       order                             Freq
Cassava           Cupertino      老大哥 - 牛肉麵 Beef Noodle Soup    10
Cassava           Cupertino      冷凍）老大哥 - LDG Frozen           7
Joy  Restaurant   SF             Beef Noodle                        30 
Joy  Restaurant   OAK            Beef Noodle                        30
```

want 3 (frequencies orders per vendor, location, day, order):

```
Vendor            day     location       order                            freq
Cassava           Wed     Cupertino      老大哥 - 牛肉麵 Beef Noodle Soup   10
Cassava           Wed     Cupertino      冷凍）老大哥 - LDG Frozen          5
Cassava           Thu     Cupertino      冷凍）老大哥 - LDG Frozen          2
Joy  Restaurant   Wed     SF              Beef Noodle                      10
Joy  Restaurant   Thu     SF              Beef Noodle                      20       
Joy  Restaurant   Wed     OAK             Beef Noodle                      30
```

want 4 (frequencies orders per vendor, day ):

```
Vendor            day     freq
Cassava           Wed     15   
Cassava           Thu     2 
Joy  Restaurant   Wed     30
Joy  Restaurant   Thu     20
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Using `dplyr`, you can do `df %>% group_by(Vendor, order) %>% summarise(sum = sum(freq))`. Change the values in `group_by` based on whose frequency you want to count.

Comment: I received an error message: "> DFnew2 <- DFnew %>% group_by(Vendor, `Product name`) %>% summarise(sum = sum(freq))
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `sum`.
x object 'freq' not found
i Input `sum` is `sum(freq)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: Vendor = "Cassava", Product name = "Cassava - “Dino”<U+725B><U+808B><U+6392><U+5957><U+9910> Beef \"Dino\" Rib Dinner Meal Kit"."

Comment: Use the column name present in your data. If it is called `qty` , use `sum(qty)`.